# How to have ggplot grouped bar graph showing percentages according to each group in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, percentage, geom-bar

I have a df with a variable a that contains two strings "stringA1" and "stringA2". It also has a variable b that contains three strings "StringB1", "stringB2" and "stringB3".

What I need is a graph grouped by variable b and showing the percentage of "stringA1" and "stringA2" within each group.

I followed the advice posted on the link below: https://sebastiansauer.github.io/percentage_plot_ggplot2_V2/

And translated to fit my data:

```
p <- ggplot(STW, aes(x=STW$Q071_3, group=STW$Q01))+
   geom_bar(mapping = aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..), x=STW$Q071_3),   
   stat="count")+
   scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent)+
   facet_grid(~Q01)+
p
```

This, however, gives me a graph with above 100% and I cannot find the error.

I have tried to play around with `(..count..)/sum(..count..)`, but did not get any useful results.

How can I solve this? Thank you and let me know if I should post more information - this is the first post I am making here and I hope to be concise and clear :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trying out, I removed the `x=STW$` and the `STW$` from `group=STW$Q01` and it all works perfectly now, although I do not know the reasons.

Here the fixed code:

```
p <- ggplot(STW, aes(Q071_3, group=Q01))+
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), stat="count")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent)+
  facet_grid(~Q01)
p
```